# Where can I find the web enhancement for the Tome of Battle?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle, online-resources

So I found this link:

https://wiki.rpg.net/index.php/Absolute_Steel_Stance

That says its text was taken from a web enhancement for the Tome of Battle, however the link returns a 404 error. Anyone knows if that enhancement is still abailable?

Comment: Since I confirmed that the advice in the duplicate question still works, and have the link available, for your convenience that particular page can be found [here](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20061225a). Note that that web enhancement does **not** make content from *Tome of Battle* free or open, and so rpg.net is most likely infringing Wizards of the Coast’s copyright with that page. It is up to Wizards of the Coast to police and enforce that, however.

Comment: Welp, the wayback machine did not have a snapshot for that page and for some reason putting archive before the url returned a strange error. Seems I was just wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, but I thought the web enhancement *added* content rather than just being maneuver cards, seems I was double mistaken.

Comment: The cards **are** added content—the added content being the layout and typesetting in printer-friendly card format. That’s a non-trivial amount of work, and an extra value above and beyond what the book has. But no, there aren’t any additional maneuvers beyond those found in *Tome of Battle*.